# Issuing Redshift COPY command via psql never acknowledges completion

Tags: bash, postgresql, shell, amazon-redshift

I have a shell script that issues a command similar to this:

```
$PGSQL_BIN/psql $RSCONNECTION -c "COPY property.history from 's3://my-bucket/data.txt.gz' CREDENTIALS 'aws_access_key_id=XXXXX;aws_secret_access_key=XXXXX' CSV DELIMITER AS ',' ACCEPTINVCHARS TRUNCATECOLUMNS GZIP TRIMBLANKS BLANKSASNULL EMPTYASNULL DATEFORMAT 'auto' ACCEPTANYDATE COMPUPDATE ON MAXERROR 100;"
```

The command is successful, but the completion is never acknolowdged, so the shell script does not move onto the next command.

Is there something I'm missing that will make this behave?

Comment: You mean that the `psql` command never returns? What do you see in `pg_stat_activity`?

Comment: what version of psql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`psql` is probably losing touch with the session. Make sure you've followed the "Change TCP/IP Timeout Settings" instructions from the Redshift Docs. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/connecting-firewall-guidance.html#connecting-firewall-guidance.change-tcpip-settings